# Converter script perl em php

Tags: php, perl

tenho um script em perl funcionando certinho e um script em php tbm funcionando certinho.

a unica diferença entre os 2 é que o meu arquivo perl tem um comando que faz um return para o outro script que o chama , e o meu php não tem isso, preciso saber como fazer no php um return similar a este. 
Segue abaixo os detalhes:

**Parte do script que gera as variáveis para mandar para a função de return**

```
foreach (split(/\n/,$uaresponse->content)) {
        my $jdata = decode_json($_);
        for ( $jdata->{result}[0]->{alternative}[0] ) {
                $response{utterance}  = encode('utf8', $_->{transcript});
                $response{confidence} = $_->{confidence};
        }
}
warn "$name The response was:\n", $uaresponse->content if ($debug);

foreach (keys %response) {
        warn "$name Setting variable: $_ = $response{$_}\n" if ($debug);
        print "SET VARIABLE \"$_\" \"$response{$_}\"\n";
        checkresponse();
}
```

**Script do perl que da o return**

```
 sub checkresponse {
        my $input = <STDIN>;
        my @values;

        chomp $input;
        if ($input =~ /^200 result=(-?\d+)\s?(.*)$/) {
                warn "$name Command returned: $input\n" if ($debug);
                @values = ("$1", "$2");
        } else {
                $input .= <STDIN> if ($input =~ /^520-Invalid/);
                warn "$name Unexpected result: $input\n";
                @values = (-1, -1);
        }
        return @values;
}
```

tentei fazer isso aqui no php mas evidente que não é assim por não funcionou.

```
$return = '("'.$resposta.'", "'.$result['sessionId'].'", "'.$andamento.'")';

return $return;
```

repare que no perl eu estou retornando 2 variáveis mas com a necessidade de modificação do sistema fiz um php que retorna 3 argumentos para funcionar da forma que preciso

**Obs: estou utilizando php 5.1.6 neste servidor e centos 5.11**

alguém poderia me ajudar ? Fico agradecido des de já a sua atenção

Answer (score 0):

arroba na frente da variável em perl nada mais é do que um array, então ficaria algo semelhante a isso:

```
<?php

function checkresponse(){
    $input = "200 result=55 abc";

    $values = array();

    if(preg_match("/^200 result=(-?\d+)\s?(.*)$/", $input, $matches)){
        array_shift($matches);
        $values = $matches;
    } else {
        $values = array(-1, -1);
    }


    return $values;



}

print_r(checkresponse());



?>
```

Comment: humm vou testar obrigado

Comment: olha ainda não consegui pois não entendi com o o meu script em perl retorna os dados . eu fiz o scritp php fazer o q ele faz mas o script em perl de alguma forma passa isso para o script principal e eu nao sei como